# Edit bar chart column names and background?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am using `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and `\usepackage{bchart}` to make a bar chart. I am trying to make some modifications on the current one Like I want to make the name of each to bar to be skewed to the left. And how to add horizontal line for each percentage number?

The code I developed is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bchart}


\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={Name1, Name2, Name3},
            xtick=data,
            ylabel=Percentage(\%),
          ]


            \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB1] coordinates {
                (Name1, 44.71) 
                (Name2, 26.57) 
                (Name3, 45.42 ) 
            };


        \end{axis}


    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I interpreted your directions correctly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bchart}


\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={Name1, Name2, Name3},
            xtick=data,
            ylabel=Percentage(\%),
            xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
            ymajorgrids,yminorgrids,minor y tick num=4,
          ]


            \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB1] coordinates {
                (Name1, 44.71) 
                (Name2, 26.57) 
                (Name3, 45.42 ) 
            };


        \end{axis}


    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Without `yminorgrids,minor y tick num=4`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @marmot, I am wondering if there is a way to make only one horizontal line from the number without additional lines?

Comment: @User3700 If you only want the major grid lines, just remove `yminorgrids,minor y tick num=4,`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for bothering but I would like to ask you about how to control the size of the bar itself

Comment: @User3700 The height of the bars is in the data, but you can make the plot higher or lower by playing with height and width, e.g. replace `\begin{axis}[` by `\begin{axis}[height=4cm,width=5cm,` or so.

Comment: sorry for my miss-clarification I meant the width of the bar if a want to enlarge it, the height is definitely depends on the data as you mentioned.

Comment: @User3700 You could add `bar width=30pt,` to the options of the axis, say.